# Debug full screen app in XCode with one computer

Tags: xcode, macos

When I set a breakpoint for an app which is currently running in full screen mode, I can not switch to any other screen when the breakpoint is reached. I'm stuck in the full screen app. The only chance I have is to hard reset the machine. I just found a single 7 year old post with Google that exactly describes my dilemma. There MUST be a solution (except having a 2nd machine) after 7 years seeing how much Apple is promoting this dreaded full screen mode.

Comment: Can you not set a shortcut up in keyboard preferences to "move left/right a space" or set up a gesture? My understanding is that these tasks should not pass through to the app, as they should be intercepted by the os

Comment: @JoeDaniels I did that, but it does not leave the current screen :-(

Comment: What if you add a code block to the breakpoint that executes an nstask to run an AppleScript that refocuses Xcode? (ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163433/can-you-execute-an-applescript-script-from-a-swift-application) in theory, Xcode should automatically activate when you have a breakpoint...

Comment: @JoeDaniels I might try, though saddling a dead horse (which AppleScript definitely is) seems not to be very promising.