# AppleEvents: received mach msg which wasn't complex type as expected in getMemoryReference

Tags: objective-c, macos, macos-high-sierra, appleevents

I am on Xcode 9.2, OSX, Objective-C.

Since OSX High Sierra Update, i get a lot of error messages logged like this:

```
AppleEvents: received mach msg which wasn't complex type as expected in getMemoryReference.
```

I have two XPC Services handling apple events for me, both of them report this.
Any clue what this is? I found a discussion in the Apple developer forums but they are not any further: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88126

ANY help or pointer in the right direction appreciated.

Comment: That's exactly what i already mentioned..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Major approach on that issue (after there happened nothing for a long time): Apple responded in the forum above - it will be hopefully removed within a future update - I'll follow up on this.

> A developer was worried about this message and so they opened a DTS tech support incident to verify whether it’s harmful or not.  I discovered the underlying cause of this message and I’m satisfied that it’s just log spam, that is, it’s annoying because it fills up the log with junk but it has no other deleterious effects.
>
> There’s a bug on file (r. 33758979) requesting that we remove this log spam.

[UPDATE]: Removed in Xcode 12