# Quit simulator programmatically swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an alert window in my code with two buttons 'Ok' and 'Exit'. I want quit simulator when 'Exit' is pressed.

```
func alertWindow() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Isn't type of gesture", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Exit", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        // Quite simulator here
    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "quit simulator", quitting the app running in the simulator?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible and there is no need to do it, except while you test your app.
You should write a testing script that will be executed when you test your app. Then you should add something like this in your script:

```
sudo killall "iOS Simulator"
```

After that, you can call the script within the code with something like this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163433/can-you-execute-an-applescript-script-from-a-swift-application) (Check 1st & 2nd answers)

Answer (score 0):

There is *NO* legit way of doing it in iOS like Android. The only way you can do what you want is to force a crash on pressing the `Exit` button.

For example, declare an optional variable with `nil` value and unwrap it, although it is not recommended to exit your app this way.

Comment: or you could just call `fatalError()` but either way Apple may reject it if they discover that