# Open Safari Extensions Preferences in macOS Catalyst

Tags: safari-extension, mac-catalyst

How am I supposed to open the Safari Extension Preferences window with the user click of a button in macOS Catalyst? It looks like the [API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariapplication/2202266-showpreferencesforextension) is not available for Catalyst.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with an AppleScript

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        keystroke "," using command down
        click button 9 of toolbar 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

The button 9 of the toolbar should be the extension panel

You could look in this answer to execute the AppleScript inside the code of your application
[Can you execute an Applescript script from a Swift Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163433/can-you-execute-an-applescript-script-from-a-swift-application#30040347)

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't able to run an Apple Script on macOS Catalyst