# How to set window size in XCUITest?

Tags: swift, macos, xctest, xcuitest

I want to do some screenshot-snapshot testing for my OSX application. For that obviously, I need the screenshots to be the same size every time. So **how can I set the size of the main window of my application in XCUITests?**

Answer (score 1):

The test code can't reach into the app code. It's up to the app code to set the window size. The app can check a condition to learn that it is under test and can respond by preparing the interface as desired.

Comment: I as a user can't reach into the internals of the app too, but I have no problem resizing the window. Other test frameworks do not reach into internals of the app as well, but they still resize the window.

Comment: But I do appreciate your answer, I'll see if I can use command line variables or something like that to control the window size.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your best bet will be to use AppleScript.

```
tell application "MyApp"
  set bounds of front window to {300, 30, 1200, 900}
end tell
```

300 is top-left-x, 30 is top-left-y, 1200 is width, and 900 is height.

[Can you execute an Applescript script from a Swift Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163433/can-you-execute-an-applescript-script-from-a-swift-application) explains how to execute AppleScript in Swift.