# How to add shake gesture with Swift XCUITest?

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing

Is there a way to programmatically trigger a shake gesture in a Swift UI test?

Comment: Mind sharing with us what you've tried? Are you having a problem you aim to fix by triggering this manually? Could mocking solve this?

Comment: What usage would that have?

Answer (score 0):

This is not presently supported in XCUITest, but has been a common request over the years. This will not work headless, but AFAIK there isn't a way to run an iOS simulator in headless mode (maybe CI does it?), using AppleScript to trigger the menu item is the only way:

```
tell application "Simulator" to activate
tell application "System Events"
  keystroke "z" using {control down, command down}
end tell
```

You could also have your script select the specific menu items rather than using a keyboard shortcut, but I think this might be more error prone:

```
tell application "Simulator" to activate
tell application "System Events"
  tell process "Simulator"
    click menu item "Shake" of menu "Device" of menu bar 1
  end tell
end tell
```

[Can you execute an Applescript script from a Swift Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163433/can-you-execute-an-applescript-script-from-a-swift-application) explains how to execute AppleScript in Swift.